# Cant do operation in PCDATA node

Tags: xml, delphi

Im try populate a node of a Xml file. I write a helper class to write/read the xml files generated by my app.
The constructor creates the next xml structure:

```
<raiz>
  <proyecto>
    <obra>Shopping</obra>
    <cliente>Pepito</cliente>
    <ubicacion>NO 24° S 32°</ubicacion>
    <fecha>08/07/2013</fecha>
    <sondeo>4</sondeo>
    <estudio>21</estudio>
    <nFreatico>3,52</nFreatico>
  </proyecto>
  <muestras/>
  <enps/>
</raiz>
```

This works fine. Now, i try add subnodes to *muestras* node. An example of a *muestra* subnode:

```
<muestra numero=1 />
```

My helper class have the **agregarMuestra(nro: integer);** method, thats try insert the subnode.
The code is:

```
procedure TXmlManager.agregarMuestra(nro: Integer);
var
  sMuestras, nNodo: IXMLNode;
  count: integer;
begin
  // Get the "muestra" node 
  sMuestras := self.getMuestraSection();
  // Insert the new node 
  count := sMuestras.ChildNodes.Count;
  nNodo := sMuestras.AddChild('muestra',count);
  nNodo.Attributes['numero'] := IntToStr(nro);
  xmLastModification := Now();
end;
```

The apps fails, in execution time, with the message in the post title. And the debuger hightlight the line:

```
  nNodo.Attributes['numero'] := IntToStr(nro);
```

Im newest work with Xml. Whats happens ?. Any ideas ?.

Comment: Are you setting the `doNodeAutoIndent` value in the `options` property?

Comment: remove that value (`doNodeAutoIndent`) and try again.

Comment: @RRUZ mother of god ! works ! gracias :)